# Web Part Editor Part is not visible

Tags: 2007, web-part

I have a problem with Custom Webpart configuration on Sharepoint 2007.

I have 2 environments - dev environment and production.

My Custom WebPart has Editor Part as a part of configuration and I can see it on my dev environment but on production env it's not shown.

On both env, I'm using IE 11. But tried with compatibility mode also.

Have you ever had similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Normally its not possible, you might have one of below problem.

1. In Dev machine, you directly deployed web part from visual studio. and you might copy old WSP to production env. here, you need to publish WSP and redeploy.
2. Check WSP is installed properly in central admin of production machine.
3. Are you getting any error while trying to edit page in production machine to add webpart ?
   if yes, what is that ? is it related to Assembly ?
4. WebPart is part of pre define in Page which is part of SP module and part of solution ?

If possible share some more information.